# tSNE on OCTMNIST dataset (part of MedMNIST) not working

Tags: classification, data-visualization, tsne

I have been trying to generate the tSNE plot for the OCTMNIST dataset which is a part of  MedMNIST v2(https://medmnist.com/). The code that I have been using is-

```
from tsne_torch import TorchTSNE as TSNE
X = torch.tensor(x.clone().detach()[:10000, :], dtype=torch.float)
X_emb = TSNE(n_components=2, perplexity=30., n_iter=1000, verbose=True).fit_transform(X)
```

The plot that I get from this is the following-
[image]

Here, x is just the raw data with dimensions [dataset_size, 28*28]. Am I doing something wrong, or the tSNE method itself is unable to separate the classes?

Comment: t-SNE is very sensitive to hyper-parameters. You can try changing these parameters a bit. Also, remind that t-SNE is very hard to interpret and is very often useless except for visualization purposes.

Comment: @Lelouch I tried tuning the perplexity parameter quite a bit, but to no avail.